# How to run normal windows .exe in raspberry PI running Windows IOT core

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I am very much new to windows core platform.

i have developed a console application in my normal windows 10 host machine using visual studio 2015 and it is working like a champ in local machine using intel(I5/I7) Processors.

Now i have to move my application to PI running windows IOT core. i did xcopy of my files and trying to run using power shell of my windows host machine but thing is.. i could not able to run my application and getting below error message.

why my application is not running in PI? In fact my application is compiled for X86 platforms for intel processors. is this the really cause?? if so how do i compile my source code to target for ARM processors. please let me know the workaround. thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like an architecture mismatch, it looks like a .NET Framework mismatch.  (Your code must be AnyCPU, because none of the other options would run both on Intel and also on ARM, and clearly your code is starting to run)

The exception occurs inside log4net, one of the libraries you use.  You will have to find a version of log4net that works on that .NET Framework version, or remove that library and find a different way to generate logs.

Answer (score 0):

Windows IoT Core supports UWP and non-UWP app. IoT Core is a UWP centric OS and UWP apps are its primary app type.Universal Windows Platform (UWP) is a common app platform across all version of Windows 10, including Windows 10 IoT Core. 
In addition to the traditional UI apps, IoT Core has added a new UWP app type called "Background Applications". These applications do not have a UI component, but instead have a class that implements the "IBackgroundTask" interface.

IoT Core supports certain traditional Win32 app types such as Win32 Console Apps,but only C++ is supported for developing Win32 apps on IoT Core.

Answer (score 0):

If you open powershell and CD into the solution project folder

To compile your code for raspberry pi, you need to compile it using win-arm as target

You can issue one of the commands:

```
dotnet publish -c Debug -r win-arm    
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-arm
```

It will then compile it into the bin folder relative to the publish profile you have chosen

'..\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\win-arm\publish'

Copy all the content of the publish folder into a directory of choice on the raspberry pi.

This will be able to run a simple .NET Core console app on a raspberry pi running Windows IoT Core